# Responsive Megamenu issue

Tags: html, css, nav, megamenu

I have created a mega menu. It works fine but I want to make few changes. But I am not able figure out on how to do it. I want to make the navigation bar width to cover the full width of the web. Then I want the megamenu to be as shown in this screenshot. How can I achieve this. Help please. Here is my code http://codepen.io/anon/pen/FpuDK/ [image]

Comment: Your codepen link in incorrect.

Comment: Oh I am sorry. Now i updated with the correct url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't this work? Add this in the end of your CSS.

```css
#nav ul.subs {width: 100%;}
```

It worked for me! :)

---

Or if I understood wrong, you want the mega menu to start from the menu's left position. If that's the case, you need to `position` the menu links as `relative` and the mega menu as `absolute`.

The solution for this is:

```css
#nav > li {position: relative;}
#nav ul.subs {position: absolute; width: 500px;}
```

I guess you can take it forward from here:

#### Preview

[image]

#### Fiddle: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rsyDJ/